# Программирование ASM MS-DOS в реальном режиме процессора на Linux

Tags: linux, ассемблер, dos

Какие инструменты нужно использовать для программирования ASM MS-DOS в реальном режиме процессора  на Linux?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/345748/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кратко, то понадобится:

- Редактор (на свой вкус)
- Ассемблер, на свой вкус/потребности, например нативный (`masm`/`tasm`) или кросс-платформенный (`nasm`/`fasm`), самый простой выбор ИМХО — `nasm`
- Эмулятор DOS'а/виртуальная машина с установленным DOS'ом, проще всего — `dosbox`.
- Отладчик — скорей всего какой-то нативный под DOS (`AFDPRO`/`CodeView`/`DeGlucker`, все не свободные, но легкодоступные), но при *особом* желании можно воспользоваться и встроенным в виртуальную машину, например qemu+gdb.

Для учебных целей всего этого будет более чем достаточно.